# Database pricing tables aggregation issue

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm using MS access for my work and have an issue that took me way too long to solve myself, so i decided to ask a you, guys. The question is next:
I have two tables for pricing: a_prices

```
article5    a_price from_date   to_date
00009       952.00  01/01/2012  31/12/2013
00009       720.00  01/01/2014  31/12/2015
00009       750.00  01/01/2016  31/12/2199
```

and a_client_prices

```
client_id   article5    a_price from_date   to_date
1           00009       700     31/12/2014  11/09/2015
2           00009       800     05/10/2015  07/04/2016
```

The problem is to make a query that returns a table of prices for exact client, so if input of that query were "where client_id=1" the resulting table would look like next:

```
article5    a_price from_date   to_date
00009       952.00  01/01/2012  31/12/2013
00009       720.00  01/01/2014  30/12/2014
00009       700     31/12/2014  11/09/2015
00009       720.00  12/09/2014  31/12/2015
00009       750.00  01/01/2016  31/12/2199
```

And if client_id=2 then:

```
article5    a_price from_date   to_date
00009       952.00  01/01/2012  31/12/2013
00009       720.00  01/01/2014  04/10/2015
00009       800     05/10/2015  07/04/2016
00009       750.00  08/04/2016  31/12/2199
```

So inside the query there should be something like overlap-excluding mechanism, where a_client_prices have higher priority, but i can't imagine anything better then join table which contain record for every day, exclude excessive records and then aggregate it back to periods.

Take into consideration, that i'm using ms access, so i can easily use custom aggregation function, if you could advise one. I feel it could be one of the solutions, but have poor experience in that field to understand how to design one myself.  Thanks for your help in advance, sorry if i missed the answer posted before that. Feel free to judge the initial data organization and propose other possibilities.

P.S. The solution with day by day aggregation is perfectly working, but take way too much processing time and the query is used way too much, so this solution was rejected.

Comment: Depending on how you intend to use these prices you may not have to create a full view of the pricing for every possible date. You might be able to use VBA to create a custom lookup function, e.g.,  `LookupPrice(client_ID, article5, effective_date)` that returns the corresponding `a_price`.

Comment: Before a_client_prices occurred i used table a_price in order to join it in queries with other data tables, so the obvious solution for me was to recreate same interface with a sub-query and use it instead, but now i see it takes to much processing time, and i still want to avoid temp tables and VBA due to impossibility of implementation in a query and lookup functions due to its slowness in large scale. Last idea i'm testing now is just to join both tables and take values in needed order(if record not is null in a_client_prices take a_price there, else take joined record from a_prices).

Comment: Bad thing about solution with joining both tables is that now i have to rewrite almost 20 queries to contain new joins. But as i cried out in this thread many times, it seems there is no hope for easy-go solution. Thanks for your piece of advice, because i forgot about this option even if i don't like it much.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of simply *assuming* that a particular approach will "obviously" be too slow; test it. I just did a DLookup() over the network on a linked table with one million rows and it took just 0.1 seconds to find the one row of interest (based on numeric ID, text and date range). That sort of approach in a query returning a relatively small number of rows might be preferable to re-working your application to use a complicated join or building a temporary table to give you all possible prices, most of which you may not need.

Comment: I will try in that exact case, but already tried it in oracle and it took way too much time on large scale comparing to joining table. In case I have now the original table is 22m records and a_prices + a_client_prices tables are about 20k. The most recent query is the aggregated original table with joined tables, one of which is prices table. This will make look up approach work several minutes comparing to seconds of native sql join style. But i will give it a chance anyway. Probably the reason why i asked the question in the very beginning is my programming way of thinking in the SQL field.

Comment: If these are Oracle tables then perhaps there is something that can be done server-side to support your task? (Stored procedure, table-valued function, ...?)

Comment: My actual problem is on MS Access. Just mentioned my previous experience on Oracle with lookup functions with large samples like a counterargument to that solution. DB with large tables very sensitive to look up procedure solutions comparing to proper SQL joins. That is the lesson i learned crashing the server using function of record on table with around 1000M records, after that i always try to avoid it on scales and use native SQL solution with joining sub-queries. Sorry for asking a question and finally doing it my way. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.^_^

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with a query.

You are taking this source record:

```
00009       720.00  01/01/2014  31/12/2015
```

and splitting it up into two records, changing the date fields on the fly:

```
00009       720.00  01/01/2014  30/12/2014
00009       720.00  12/09/2014  31/12/2015
```

And this is just one of several different cases.

No aggregation function will do this. You need a VBA solution, walking through the recordsets, and creating the target records in a new table.

**Edit**

My approach for calculating one client's price list would be:

- delete * from temp table
- Insert * from `a_prices` into temp table
- for each record in `a_client_prices`:
- - if it "fits" into one date range: duplicate that, adapt from- & to-dates
- - if it overlaps two date ranges: adapt both records to exclude the new date range
- - insert `a_client_prices` record into temp table

It needs quite a bit of logic, but should be really fast.

Comment: The reason i asked the question is because i know the solution which looks like splitting every record by day, then aggregating back, it's not fast enough in a way of processing time, but it could be done. Probably you could advise another way of data organization so this kind of query could be done easier?

Comment: Hm... probably it could be a solution, but the prices are used and changed pretty frequently in a client-side, table a_prices is huge, and the process of recreating summary table could take some time to do every single time something is changed, that's why I've tried to avoid temp table and pack it into sub-query, that i can easily be joined into any query i need.

Comment: I think you're right, i'm just over-complicating things with a hope that there should be easy, fast and sub-query solution without using VBA and preprocessed summary table. Thanks a lot.